# При запуске .bat файла из-под node js не может найти исполняемый .exe

Tags: javascript, node.js, bat

такая проблема, есть папка с программой, которая стартует через .bat файл, когда я запускаю этот бат вручную, все хорошо запускается, но мне нужно сделать запуск через node js, и когда я это делаю, то вылазит ошибка что .bat файл не может найти .exe который ему нужно запустить.
Код запуска:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', botFile]);
bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(data.toString());
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

.bat файл:

```
    Start /min fleamarket.exe "fleamarketstart.cms"
    exit
```

Путь к .bat прописан правильно, сам файл запускается, но он уже не видит .exe который должен запустить, лежат .bat и .exe в одной папке, когда вручную клацаю, все работает, проблема только через node js.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, ваш нодовский скрипт и bat-файл лежат в разных папках. Тогда, если вы запускаете нодовский скрипт из его папки, текущей папкой становится папка скрита, тогда bat-файл ищет .exe  в этой папке и не находит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я все таки не нашел решения чтобы сделать это как я написал выше, но данное более чем мне подошло, я просто исполняю команду из .bat файла прямо в node js, указав полный путь на .exe файл. Теперь это выглядит так:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
let botFile = path.resolve(__dirname + '/bot/', 'fleamarket.exe');
exec(`Start /min ${botFile} "fleamarketstart.cms" exit`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```